# Kerberos setup and Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, kerberos

I'm newbie to Kerberos but I need to provide SSO Kerberos auth to web application. 
Flow of my application looks like this:

1) User makes GET on url

2) Checking if there is Authorization if no then 401 WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate

3) Using header I create KerberosServiceRequestToken

4) Using SpringSecurity KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider it tries to verify but I'm always getting exception:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: GSSContext name of the context initiator is null
```

Configuration in SpringSecurity:

```
    public KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider() {
    KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider provider = new KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setTicketValidator(sunJaasKerberosTicketValidator());
    return provider;
}
public SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator sunJaasKerberosTicketValidator() {
    SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator validator = new SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator();
    validator.setServicePrincipal("HTTP/principal");
    validator.setKeyTabLocation(new ClassPathResource("kerberos/http-web.keytab"));
    validator.setDebug(true);
    return validator;
}
```

}

Comment: Is your app based on any of the Spring Security Kerberos Samples? - http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#springsecuritykerberossamples

Comment: Not exactly. I have app that is divided on two parts:
- frontend which is Vaadin app
- backend which is Spring REST (MVC) app 
Backend is protected using spring security and custom TokenFilter. Frontent send header taken from browser lets say:
Authorization: Negotiate Y..
Backend verifies header and if everything is ok send back Token and allow user to perform requests. The trouble is that I need to provide SSO based on Kerberos. I have active directory installed and I need to connect to it through Kerberos. The second thing is that AD is on different server that app but is visible through VPN

Comment: If you're not to far into your solution, I'd like to suggest that you follow example 6 from that list in the link, which is a hello world with Kerberos + AD. Then try and integrate with your existing solution.

Comment: I found this question - I'm actually using example from chapter 6 (current 1.0.2 snapshot), I changed YML file, I can browse AD with other client, but I got this error when I access the application with Firefox (`network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris` is set to my domain). I'm running demo on Windows computer in the domain (not on DC). These samples are rather sketchy for Kerberos non-experts. I don't know if I should use `krb5.ini`, or if I need keytab file when I'm on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Change the keytab location to a file based location and remove it from the classpath.

Here is a sample:

```
validator.setKeyTabLocation(new FileSystemResource("kerberos/http-web.keytab"));
```

P.S. Do not forget to set the `UserDetailService` in `KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider`.

If this does not solve the issue, check if your application is getting the correct SPNEGO token. You might not be getting correct token unless all other settings are in place.